# how to submit a <form action=" " > using sweet alert. because it must be use "action". I usually using href

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I get trouble when using sweet alert on my submit a form, I usually use a href but it must use form action 
I don't know :(

```
<form class="form-horizontal text-right m-b-1" action="<?php echo base_url('pegawai/editfoto') ?>" method="POST">

                        <div class="col-9 ">
                            <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                                <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail " style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$data[0]->foto)?>" alt="image" class="img-fluid" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom btn-file">
                                        <span class="fileupload-new"><i class="fa fa-paper-clip"></i> Select image</span>
                                        <span class="fileupload-exists"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Change</span>
                                        <input type="file" name="foto" class="btn-light" />
                                    </button>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <div class="form-group account-btn text-center m-t-10">
                              <div class="col-12">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn w-lg btn-rounded btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" id="sa-editfoto" >Save</button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </form>
```

and the code of sweet alert

```
$('#sa-editfoto').click(function () {
          var link= $(this).attr("link-href")
          $('#sa-editfoto').attr("src", link);
            swal({
                title: 'Apakah Anda Yakin?',
                text: "Foto Profile akan diubah",
                type: 'question',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-confirm mt-2',
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-cancel ml-2 mt-2',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
            }).then(function () {
              window.location.href = link;
            })
        });
```

help me if you know the answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to get a confirmation from the user and once confirmed you are planning to submit the form. For that you need to add little changes to your code as below,

a. Add id to your form control as below,

```
<form id="form1" class="form-horizontal text-right m-b-1" action="<?php echo base_url('pegawai/editfoto') ?>" method="POST">
```

b. Check whether user confirmed the submit on the javascript of sweet alert as below,

```
       swal({
            title: 'Apakah Anda Yakin?',
            text: "Foto Profile akan diubah",
            type: 'question',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-confirm mt-2',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-cancel ml-2 mt-2',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
        }).then(function (isConfirmed) {
           // If user confirmed submit the form
           if(isConfirmed)
              $("#form1").submit();
        })
```

Hope it helps.